# Validation for RadioButtonList in Asp.net with JavaScript and Value Fetched from Database

Tags: asp.net, database, radiobuttonlist

I want to use JavaScript Validation on RadioButtonList where Values are binded by existed table #tblGender where given three value Male, Female and Others. I want to show that if any button is not checked then return an error 'Please Choose at least 1 button'.

Comment: Please show us your code, thus you can understand your question better.

Comment: function chkGender() {
            var rb = document.getElementsByName("rblgender");
            var isrbChecked = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < rb.length; i++) {
                if (rb[i].checked) {
                    isrbChecked++; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isrbChecked == true)
                return "";
            else return "Please Choose Gender.\n";
        }

Comment: Add codes to your question please

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript you can something like this:

```
function IsRadioButtonSelected() {
    var arrRadio = document.getElementsByName("NameOfRadioButton"),
        c = 0;
    return arrRadio.forEach(function(item, index) {
        item.checked && c++
    }), c > 0
}
```

And call it like this:

```
if(IsRadioButtonSelected()){
    alert('Radio Button is Selected')
}
else{
    alert('Radio Button is not Selected')
}
```

...but if you use jQuery it can be much simple like this :

```
if($("input[name=NameOfRadioButton]:checked").length>0){
    alert('Radio Button is Selected')
}else{
    alert('Radio Button is not Selected')
}
```